# SmartyBC (Backwards Compatibility Wrapper) doesn't work in PrestaShop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

As adviced in Smarty's instruction, in order to use deprecated functions like `include_php` in newest PrestaShop, I had to switch from `Smarty.class.php` to `SmartyBC.class.php`. I did it by modyfing in `smarty.config.inc.php` following lines:

```
require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'SmartyBC.class.php');
// require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'Smarty.class.php');

global $smarty;
// $smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
```

However, using `{include_php file='./custom_php/manufacturers.php'}` in theme's `header.tpl` still results in blank screen. Errors from php_error_log :

```
[22-Jul-2014 15:05:55 Europe/Warsaw] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: SmartyBC::$trusted_dir in C:\BACKUP\Dropbox\!_PC\LOCALHOST\_INTERCLICK\trzmiel5\tools\smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 676

[22-Jul-2014 15:05:55 Europe/Warsaw] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template &quot;C:\BACKUP\Dropbox\!_PC\LOCALHOST\_INTERCLICK\trzmiel5\themes\trzmiel\header.tpl&quot;  on line 101 &quot;{include_php file='./custom_php/manufacturers.php'}&quot; {include_php} file './custom_php/manufacturers.php' is not readable' in C:\BACKUP\Dropbox\!_PC\LOCALHOST\_INTERCLICK\trzmiel5\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:667
Stack trace:
#0 C:\BACKUP\Dropbox\!_PC\LOCALHOST\_INTERCLICK\trzmiel5\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_compile_include_php.php(81): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->trigger_template_error('{include_php} f...', 101)
#1 C:\BACKUP\Dropbox\!_PC\LOCALHOST\_INTERCLICK\trzmiel5\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(485): Smarty_Internal_Compile_Include_Php->compile(Array, Object(Smarty_Internal_SmartyTemplateCompiler), Array, NULL, NULL)
#2 C:\BACKUP\Dropbox\!_PC\LOCALHOST\_INTERCLICK\trzmiel5\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templ in C:\BACKUP\Dropbox\!_PC\LOCALHOST\_INTERCLICK\trzmiel5\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 667
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `trusted_dir` property is available only when using Security Policy:

```
class My_Security_Policy extends Smarty_Security {
  public $trusted_dir  = './custom_php/';

}
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
// enable security
$smartyBC->enableSecurity('My_Security_Policy');
```

so you should provide here correct path (I don't know is it relative or not - you should give a try) and then you should be able to use `manufacturers.php` file in your template file but you should also here look at correct file path.